# Native Element toArray() undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm doing some refactoring on a application that I'm working on and I'm stuck.

On my HTML I have a grid with some cards using ngFor. There is a button that should "show/hide" a specific div.

My solution was to use a local variable to get the specific element and show that specific div. It was working fine, but now, I can't get it to work, I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: "this.travelInfoBox.toArray(...)[index] is undefined"
>   showBox card.component.ts:40
>      View_CardComponent_0 CardComponent.html:12

Here is the HTML for the parent component:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4" *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">
        <app-card [student]="student" [i]="i"></app-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML for the **card component**:

```html
<div class="col s12 m4 l2 right">
    <hr class="hide-on-med-and-up">
    <i class="material-icons">send</i>
    <i class="material-icons" (click)="showBox(i)">access_alarm</i>
    <span class="hide-on-med-and-up card-travel-info">Tavel Information</span>
    <app-travel-info class="card travel-info s12 m6 l4" #travelInfoBox></app-travel-info>
    <hr class="hide-on-med-and-up">
</div>
```

**TS** for the **card component**:

```js
import {Component, Input, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';            

@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})

export class CardComponent {
    @Input('student') student: any;
    @Input('i') i: any;
    @ViewChildren('travelInfoBox') private travelInfoBox: QueryList<ElementRef>;
    constructor() { }

    showBox(index) {
        const nativeElement = this.travelInfoBox.toArray()[index].nativeElement;
        nativeElement.style.display = nativeElement.style.display === 'none' || !nativeElement.style.display ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work for the first card?

Comment: No :( On this first one says "nativeElement is undefined" on the second one "this.travelInfoBox.toArray(...)[index] is undefined"

Comment: Try `@ViewChild('travelInfoBox', { read: ElementRef }) private travelInfoBox: ElementRef;` and `const nativeElement = this.travelInfoBox.nativeElement;`. If I am not mistaken, each card has only one `travelInfoBox`, so the index is not needed.

Comment: Put a breakpoint prior to the failure, switch to console window and type in this.travelbox press enter.  What do you see?

Comment: @ConnorsFan that worked! Thank you so much! So.. why in this case I don't use it as an array?

Comment: By the way, I would suggest to hide the element with `<app-travel-info *ngIf="showDiv" ...>` and to toggle  that boolean value in the event handler: `(click)="showDiv = !showDiv"`. That is more "the Angular way" than working with the `nativeElement` in code.

Comment: Thank you @ConnorsFan that makes a lot of sense. I appreciate your help.